# programming linux C client-server. Client not receiving data. localhost

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, client-server

I start a client-server progrm on localhost.
My program should send file list of local directory from server to client and client should print it. Client randomly prints some filenames (not all) or doesn't print them at all.

if I change nc for client ( nc localhost 21) or server ( sudo nc -l 21) all works.

client:

```cc
#ifndef DEBUG
#define DEBUG
#endif

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#ifndef SIZE
#define SIZE 1000
#endif

#define SERVER_PORT 21

#define CLIENT_IP 0
#define SERVER_IP 0

void recv_smth2(int skt);
int connect2(int IP, int PORT);


int main(){
  int port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
  int sck =  connect2(SERVER_IP,port);
  if (sck == -1){
    return 0;
  }
  recv_smth2(sck);
}

void recv_smth2(int skt){
  char BUF[SIZE];
  while(1){
    int l = recv(skt,BUF,SIZE-1,0);
    if(l == -1){
      perror("recv error");
    }
    BUF[l] = 0;
    printf("%s", BUF);
  }
}

int connect2(int IP, int PORT){
  //^ in network byte order^


  struct sockaddr_in addr;

  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = PORT;
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = IP;

  int skt = socket( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
  if (skt == -1){
    perror("socket error");
  }
  int cnct = connect( skt, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr) );
  if (cnct == -1){
    perror("cnct error");
    return -1;
  }
  return skt;
}
```

server:

```c
#define SERVER_PORT 21

#ifndef SIZE
#define SIZE 1000
#endif


#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include<errno.h>

#include<dirent.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>

int open_port(int PORT);
void send_string(const char *s,int n,int sk);
void send_file_list(int skt);

int main(){
  int port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
  int sk = open_port(port);
  if (sk == -1){
    perror("can't open port");
  }

  send_string("Hello!\n", sizeof("Hello!\n"), sk);
  send_file_list(sk);

 }



void send_file_list(int skt){
  char buf[SIZE];
  DIR *dir;
  struct dirent *ent;
  if((dir = opendir(".")) != NULL ){
      while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
            int n = strnlen(ent->d_name, SIZE - 2);//without \0
            snprintf(buf,n+2,"%s\n",ent->d_name);//\n\0
            send_string(buf,n+2,skt);
      }
    }
}

void send_string(const char *s, int n, int sk){
  send(sk,s,n,0);
}

// all in network byte order
int open_port(int PORT){
  struct sockaddr_in addr;

  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  //addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
  addr.sin_port = PORT;

  int skt = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  int enable = 1;
  if(setsockopt(skt,SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(int)))
     perror("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR)failed");
  bind(skt, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr));

  if(listen(skt, 0) == -1){
    perror("listen ");
    return -1;
  }
  struct sockaddr_storage addr_s;

  memset(&addr_s, 0, sizeof(addr_s));

  int addr_size = sizeof(addr_s);
  int fd = accept( skt, (struct sockaddr*) &addr_s, &addr_size);
  if (fd == -1){
    perror("accept");
  }

  if (fd != 0){
  }
  return fd;  

}
```

compile

```
gcc client.c -o client
gcc server.c -o server
run:
$ sudo ./server
$ client
```

Client should print "Hello" then list of all files in server directory.
It only prints "Hello" then randomly prints some filenames from server directory.
If I use nc instead of client I get name of every file every time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096243

Comment: Maybe I am missing something obvious, but ... Since you are using IPv4, when don't you just use `struct sockaddr_in` on the server instead of `struct sockaddr_storage`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your client is receiving all the file names, you are just ignoring some of them.

The socket API does not guarantee that each call to `recv` will produce the contents of exactly one call to `send`. The contents can be split so that you have to call `recv` many times, or joined together so you get several file names at once.

The latter is what is happening to you: The buffer you fill with `recv` in the client contains several file names, e.g.: `server.c\n\0client\n\0client.c\n\0` and so on. When you pass this to `printf`, only the buffer contents are interpreted as a string, which means that `printf` stops at the first `\0`, and the rest of the file names are ignored.

You can loop over the received contents, until reaching the length `l`, and print every character that is not `\0`. The following code does so, but maybe not in the most efficient way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if (BUF[i] != '\0')
        putchar(BUF[i]);
}
```

You might also use a loop with `strlen` and `puts`, or something similar.